# GUI issues in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: upgrade, firefox, themes, gtk, 16.10

I upgraded my laptop from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10 yesterday. Every since I upgraded the laptop, GUI elements in various applications such as firefox and Unity Tweak Tool are not rendering as they should. In the screenshot below, it can be seen that there's no space between various menus and they are all cluttered together. In Firefox, when I scroll down the right click menu, the menu object my mouse cursor is on is not highlighted etc. I'm running the i3 window manager.

I tried changing the GTK theme but it didn't help. How do I fix this issue?

[image: No spaces between Menus]

Comment: Custom themes from 16.04 may not work correctly on 16.10. Try to change to Ambiance default theme.

Comment: I am using Adapta in 16.10 and it works fine. Did you update your Adapta theme to the one built for 16.10?

Comment: @edwinksl Installed it from the PPA yesterday, so latest

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried changing it to Ambiance using UTT, it did not help.

Comment: Are you using an Nvidia card? I am experiencing the same thing and have tried the same themes as you have.

Comment: @Alex An update of the theme and a restart solved the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem, using default theme, out of the box.

Comment: Same problem here, exists with Ambiance and Radiance. It does work with Highcontrast theme.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I also found the same issues while switching GTK Themes.
The only custom theme now available for Ubuntu 16.10 is Arc GTK Theme.